# Retrieving String value of system.object basetype in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the result from the http post request and i am storing the content in a variabe.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://xxxxxx" -Method Post -Body $Body -Headers $header 
$Content =$response.Content
```

Content looks like this:

```
{"id":"246584121546545124545"}
```

Now i want only the value of the id. i tried using the select object and property  parameter to get the value of the id. But its not working as content is a string. Looks simple but couldn't find a way to retrieve the value.

```
PS C:\Scripts> $Content.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Invoke-RestMethod`.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://xxxxxx" -Method Post -Body $Body -Headers $header 
$response.id
```

#### Invoke-RestMethod

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)

> The `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet sends HTTP and HTTPS requests to Representational State Transfer (REST) web services that returns richly structured data.
>   Windows PowerShell formats the response based to the data type.
>   For JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) or XML, Windows PowerShell converts (or deserializes) the content into objects.

Comment: This is a better solution IMO

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse from JSON to a custom PS object like so, and then access the `id` property:

```
> $x = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Content
> $x.id
```